# files search with q param does not have 'or' operator?

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to fire files search with 'q' param with 'or' operator.
Intention is find files with title = 'apple' or 'orange'

```
$params = array (
  'q'=> "title = 'apple' or title = 'orange'"
);
```

however I did not find 'or' operator in the documentation.
So instead of using 'or' is it okay to use combination of 'not' and 'and' to create equivallent of 'or' as follows:

```
$params = array(
  'q'=> "not ( title !='apple' and title != 'orange' )"
);
```

Will this work?
Or how to use 'or' operator?

Comment: I think that might work, does it?

Comment: It might work if brackets are allowed in query. Question is/was that, is 'or' omitted from  the specs as design or is it a miss. If it is by design, then why? If it is a miss then will it be corrected in next release?

Comment: Ah ok, I can answer that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, OR is not currently available, but Google are working on it.

Comment: I'm really interested in such feature, will it be published?